# How to implement Null Object in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was following [this](https://refactoring.guru/introduce-null-object) example on how to do null objects. This is how far I got, before I got stuck.

### ChessPiece.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class ChessPiece: MonoBehaviour
{
    public int CurrentX{ set; get; }
    public int CurrentZ{ set; get; }

    public virtual bool[,] PossibleMove()
    {
        return new bool[8, 8];
    }

    public virtual bool isNull
    {
        get{ return false; }
    }

    public static ChessPiece NewNull()
    {
        return new GameObject("NullChessPiece").AddComponent<NullChessPiece>();
    }
}
// same file
public class NullChessPiece: ChessPiece
{
    public override bool isNull
    {
        get{ return true; }
    }
}
```

`Usage`

### Pawn.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pawn: ChessPiece
{
    public override bool[,] PossibleMove()
    {
        bool[,] result = new bool[8,8];
        // Usage
        if(!piece(0, 1).isNull) {
            result[CurrentX, CurrentZ + 2] = true;
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    
    // Each time this function is executed I get NullChessPiece objects
    // in my Hierarchy pane and they just keep on adding
    // how do I stop this?
    private ChessPiece piece(int x, int z)
    {
        return BoardManager.Instance.ChessPieces[CurrentX + x, CurrentZ + z] ??
               ChessPiece.NewNull();
    }
}
```

`Just in case you need to see what's going on here`

### BoardManager.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class BoardManager: MonoBehaviour
{
    public static BoardManager Instance{ set; get; }
    public ChessPiece[,] ChessPieces{ set; get; }
    
    private void Start()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
}
```

`GameObject("NullChessPiece").AddComponent<NullChessPiece>()` this part is throwing me off. Since there is nothing in the example about something like that in the article.

It is working, the only problem is that I keep getting many instances of `NullChessPiece`.

`//See comments for more info.`

Comment: I'm not sure I see the need for a `NullChessPiece` at all. It seems to me like the functionality you are looking for would be just as easily gained by just simply using `null`.

Comment: The whole point of Null Object it to eliminate null check completely. Since I'm only half way through you still see the null check. Theoretically there won't be any null checks when I'm done.

Comment: What's wrong with null checks? What you are doing with a "Null Object" is essentially the exact same thing you would do with a null check with the addition of a bunch of additional setup, logistics, and overhead. The only time to ever need to worry about having a "Null Object" is when your data type is a struct (which can't be null) and your `ChessPiece` is a class. All you are doing is making more work for yourself.

Comment: And a benefit of using `null` over a "Null Object" is that operations on a "Null Object" will complete with some confusing bugs that can be tricky to track down, whereas `null` will just throw a `NullReferenceException`, showing you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: According to this [article](https://refactoring.guru/introduce-null-object) null checks are unnecessary. I'm learning this technique, and I am not finished. Therefore you do not see finished product. I may not use this technique at all, but I would like to learn it first so I can decide whether to use it later. Again if done properly there won't be any null checks. Please go through the refactoring tutorial to understand what's going on.

Comment: Doing `X == null` is not any more or less verbose than `X.IsNull()`, and whichever one looks better is entirely subjective (I'd argue that the former is more transparent in its intent since `IsNull` could return false for any number of non-null-related reasons). On the other hand, using `IsNull()` makes a difficult-to-debug environment for reasons I mentioned. And although the difference would be negligible, I would also be remiss not to mention that `X == null` is much more performant than `X.IsNull()`. Unless you are working with a non-nullable type, it's just unnecessary work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using a single static null object?

```
private static ChessPiece nullInstance;

public static ChessPiece NewNull()
{
    if (nullInstance == null) 
    {
        nullInstance = new GameObject("NullChessPiece").AddComponent<NullChessPiece>();
    }

    return nullInstance;
}
```

Comment: great :) just beware.. those "null" objects should be later initialized properly with real object data, mainly because they are all referencing the same single object